# Use .htaccess to redirect files beginning with certain criteria

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I'm moving a website following a big redesign and a lot of URL structures have changed. I've managed to use .htaccess to sort most of the redirects, but I've got a lot of pages which need redirecting which begin with /shop.php?, e.g.:

/shop.php?search=as&x=0&y=0&sec=search&filter=price&filt_id=12&sort=ASC&page=1
/shop.php?sec=cat&cat=13&filter=cat&filt_id=13

Basically, I need every file beginning with /shop.php? redirecting to /shop/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
RewriteRule ^shop\.php$ /shop/? [L,R=301,NC]
```